# py2neo erroring for basic requests with neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have spent the last few months running neo4j on my local machine. I have been using py2neo to orchestrate the db with python. I have just switched to running the database on an aws ec2 instance and I am recieving errors whenever I try to send requests to the database.
I am using the following simple code to test the database, this code works perfectly on my local machine.

```
from py2neo import *

neo4j_url = 'http://localhost:7474/'
user = 'neo4j'
pwd = 'neo4j'

graph = Graph(neo4j_url, auth=(user,pwd))
print(graph)
graph.run("Create (n:Person{name: 'Andy person'})")
```

This code errors with

```
Graph('http://localhost:7474')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/KG_construction/kg-construction/KG_env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/http.py", line 443, in from_json
    content = json_loads(data, object_hook=JSONHydrant.json_to_packstream)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 370, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_connection.py", line 9, in <module>
    graph.run("Create (n:Person{name: 'Andy person'})")
  File "/home/ec2-user/KG_construction/kg-construction/KG_env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/database.py", line 405, in run
    return self.auto().run(cypher, parameters, **kwparameters)
  File "/home/ec2-user/KG_construction/kg-construction/KG_env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/database.py", line 989, in run
    result = self._connector.auto_run(cypher, parameters,
  File "/home/ec2-user/KG_construction/kg-construction/KG_env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py", line 1340, in auto_run
    return cx.auto_run(cypher, parameters, graph_name=graph_name, readonly=readonly)
  File "/home/ec2-user/KG_construction/kg-construction/KG_env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/http.py", line 177, in auto_run
    rs = HTTPResponse.from_json(r.status, r.data.decode("utf-8"))
  File "/home/ec2-user/KG_construction/kg-construction/KG_env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/http.py", line 445, in from_json
    raise_from(ProtocolError("Cannot decode response content as JSON"), error)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
py2neo.errors.ProtocolError: Cannot decode response content as JSON
```

Does anyone have idea why this error is occuring on my ec2 instance but not on my local machine?

Comment: looks like there is a problem when you copy/paste you code from local to ec2.

Comment: I'm using git so there is definitely no difference in the code between my local and ec2, and the environment is using the same python version and all the same package versions

Comment: sometimes it copies a char ^M at the end so you can convert the code from dos to unix unicode.

Comment: I'm not copy pasting the code, I'm using git

Comment: try this. open a ssh connection to your ec2 then create a file test.py using a vi editor. Then type the code manually without going thru git. Then run the script via "python test.py".   I suspect there is a hidden char in the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, no luck unfortunately. The same error occurs

Comment: I've had a look at the data that py2neo is attemping to decode and it is empty, so the error is definitely in the neo4j server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and I solved it. The problem was in the source code of py2neo. In the py2neo/database.py file, at line 990, I changed the following code :

```
else:
            result = self._connector.auto_run(cypher, parameters,
                                              graph_name="neo4j",
                                              readonly=self.readonly)
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is that when we connect to neo4j, we should write the following code :

```
graph  = Graph("http://localhost:____", auth = ("neo4j", "password"), name="neo4j")
```